# Proving the relation between sides and diagonals of parallelogram without trigonometry and Pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, quadrilateral

I am looking for a way to prove that the sum of the squares of the diagonals of parallelogram is equal to the sum of the squares of its sides. However, I would like to know whether it is possible to prove without vectors, Pythagoras theorem, cosine theorem, and trigonometric functions. Thus, I'd like to know the more elementary proof of this property.

P.S.: I know the easy way to prove this via the cosine theorem:

Consider parallelogram $ABCD$ with $BC\parallel AD$, $AB\parallel CD$.

In triangle $ABD$, by cosine theorem:

$BD^2 = AB^2+AD^2-2\cdot AB\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle BAD$.

In triangle $ADC$, by cosine theorem:

$AC^2=CD^2+AD^2-2\cdot CD\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle ADC$

Summing up these two equalities we get:

$AC^2+BD^2=CD^2+AD^2+AB^2+AD^2-2\cdot CD\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle ADC-2\cdot AB\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle BAD$

By properties of parallelogram, $AB = CD$, and $\cos\angle BAD=\cos(180^\circ - \angle ADC) = -\cos\angle ADC$

Then we have:

$AC^2+BD^2=2AB^2+2AD^2+2\cdot AB\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle ADC-2\cdot AB\cdot AD\cdot\cos\angle ADC$

It follows that:

$AC^2+BD^2=2(AB^2+AD^2)$

QED.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to establish a metric relation without some form of Pythagoras Thm or law of cosines, because either one of those encapsulates the Euclidean metric on the plane. Vectors can certainly be avoided, as you showed.

Comment: @GReyes partial, but not full, proof of Pythagoras theorem is allowed. Now, does it make it more 'established'?

Comment: All you need is the distance formula (which could be considered a partial proof of Pythagoras). Consider the parallelogram with vertices at $(0, 0), (a, 0), (a+b, c), (b, c) $. Then show that the sum of squares is exactly what you want it to be.

Comment: You can use Euclid's [II-12](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/propII12.html) and [II-13](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/propII13.html) instead of the cosine rule. But Pythagoras' theorem is used in the proofs of those theorems.